# Spark and Scala: Apply a function to each element of an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of VertexRDD[(VertexId, Long)] structured as follows:

```
(533, 1)
(571, 2)
(590, 0)
...
```

Where, each element is composed of the vertex id (533, 571, 590, etc) and its number of outgoing edges (1, 2, 0, etc).

I want to apply a function to each element of this `RDD`. This function must perform a comparison between the number of outgoing edges and 4 thresholds.

If the number of outgoing edges is less than or equal to one of the 4 thresholds then the corresponding vertex id must be inserted into an `Array` (or another similar data structure), so as to obtain at the end 4 data  structures, each containing the ids of the vertices that satisfy the omparison with the corresponding threshold.

I need that the ids that satisfy the comparison with the same threshold to be accumulated in the same data structure. How can I parallel and implement this approach with `Spark` and `Scala`?

My code:

```
val usersGraphQuery = "MATCH (u1:Utente)-[p:PIU_SA_DI]->(u2:Utente) RETURN id(u1), id(u2), type(p)"
val usersGraph = neo.rels(usersGraphQuery).loadGraph[Any, Any]
val numUserGraphNodes = usersGraph.vertices.count
val numUserGraphEdges = usersGraph.edges.count
val maxNumOutDegreeEdgesPerNode = numUserGraphNodes - 1

// get id and number of outgoing edges of each node from the graph
// except those that have 0 outgoing edges (default behavior of the outDegrees API)
var userNodesOutDegreesRdd: VertexRDD[Int] = usersGraph.outDegrees

/* userNodesOutDegreesRdd.foreach(println) 
 * Now you can see 
 *  (533, 1)
 *  (571, 2)
 */

// I also get ids of nodes with zero outgoing edges
var fixedGraph: Graph[Any, Any] = usersGraph.outerJoinVertices(userNodesOutDegreesRdd)( (vid: Any, defaultOutDegrees: Any, outDegOpt: Option[Any]) => outDegOpt.getOrElse(0L) )
var completeUserNodesOutDregreesRdd = fixedGraph.vertices

/* completeUserNodesOutDregreesRdd.foreach(println) 
* Now you can see 
*  (533, 1)
*  (571, 2)
*  (590, 0) <--
*/

// 4 thresholds that identify the 4 clusters of User nodes based on the number of their outgoing edges 
var soglia25: Double = (maxNumOutDegreeEdgesPerNode.toDouble/100)*25
var soglia50: Double = (maxNumOutDegreeEdgesPerNode.toDouble/100)*50
var soglia75: Double = (maxNumOutDegreeEdgesPerNode.toDouble/100)*75
var soglia100: Double = maxNumOutDegreeEdgesPerNode
println("soglie: "+soglia25+", "+soglia50+", "+soglia75+", "+soglia100)

// containers of individual clusters
var lowSAUsers = new ListBuffer[(Long, Any)]()
var mediumLowSAUsers = new ListBuffer[(Long, Any)]()
var mediumHighSAUsers = new ListBuffer[(Long, Any)]()
var highSAUsers = new ListBuffer[(Long, Any)]()
// overall container of the 4 clusters
var clustersContainer = new ListBuffer[ (String, ListBuffer[(Long, Any)]) ]()

// I WANT PARALLEL FROM HERE -----------------------------------------------
// from RDD to Array
var completeUserNodesOutDregreesArray = completeUserNodesOutDregreesRdd.take(numUserGraphNodes.toInt)

// analizzo ogni nodo Utente e lo assegno al cluster di appartenenza
for(i<-0 to numUserGraphNodes.toInt-1) { 
  // confronto il valore del numero di archi in uscita (convertito in stringa) 
  // con le varie soglie per determinare in quale classe inserire il relativo nodo Utente 
  if( (completeUserNodesOutDregreesArray(i)._2).toString().toLong <= soglia25 ) {
    println("ok soglia25 ")
    lowSAUsers += completeUserNodesOutDregreesArray(i)
  }else if( (completeUserNodesOutDregreesArray(i)._2).toString().toLong <= soglia50 ){
    println("ok soglia50 ")
    mediumLowSAUsers += completeUserNodesOutDregreesArray(i)
  }else if( (completeUserNodesOutDregreesArray(i)._2).toString().toLong <= soglia75 ){
    println("ok soglia75 ")
    mediumHighSAUsers += completeUserNodesOutDregreesArray(i)
  }else if( (completeUserNodesOutDregreesArray(i)._2).toString().toLong <= soglia100 ){
    println("ok soglia100 ")
    highSAUsers += completeUserNodesOutDregreesArray(i)
  }

} 

// I put each cluster in the final container
clustersContainer += Tuple2("lowSAUsers", lowSAUsers)
clustersContainer += Tuple2("mediumLowSAUsers", mediumLowSAUsers)
clustersContainer += Tuple2("mediumHighSAUsers", mediumHighSAUsers)
clustersContainer += Tuple2("highSAUsers", highSAUsers)

/* clustersContainer.foreach(println) 
 * Now you can see 
 * (lowSAUsers,ListBuffer((590,0)))
 * (mediumLowSAUsers,ListBuffer((533,1)))
 * (mediumHighSAUsers,ListBuffer())
 * (highSAUsers,ListBuffer((571,2)))
 */

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you show expected output and what have you tried?

Comment: @mtoto I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about you create an array of tuples representing different bins:

```
val bins = Seq(0, soglia25, soglia50, soglia75, soglia100).sliding(2)
    .map(seq => (seq(0), seq(1))).toArray
```

Then for each element of your RDD you find a corresponding bin, make it a key, convert id to Seq and reduce by key:

```
def getBin(bins: Array[(Double, Double)], value: Int): Int = { 
   bins.indexWhere {case (a: Double, b: Double) => a < value && b >= value} 
}
userNodesOutDegreesRdd.map { 
    case (id, value) => (getBin(bins, value), Seq(id))
}.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

Comment: Perfect!!! considering my code, is it also possible to obtain in the 4 final lists a property of the user node (ie the name) instead of its id (or even id and a property)?

I mean, now I get: (0, List (610, 590)) (1, List (627)) (3, List (571)) (2, List (533))

but I would like to get: (0, List ((610, Bob), (590, Fabian))) 
(1, List ((627, Chris)))
(3, List ((571, Frank)))
(2, List ((533, Joe)))

Comment: I'm not familiar with GraphX so I'm not sure how to extract the name, but the idea is to have RDD with 3 values `(id, name, value)` and then
`rdd.map { 
    case (id, name, value) => (getBin(bins, value), Seq((id,name)))
`}